# Java: NoSuchElementException when iterating through ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, nosuchelementexception

I want to delete duplicate elements and therefore iterate through a ArrayList and compare two consecutive elements. (Persons are comparable)

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = getHelper().findAllPersons();
Collections.sort(persons);
ListIterator<Person> it = persons.listIterator();
if(it.hasNext()) {
    Person tmp = it.next();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        if(tmp.getLastDiscovered() == it.next().getLastDiscovered()) {
            getHelper().delete(tmp);
        }
    tmp = it.next();
    }
}
```

I get a NoSuchElementException at `tmp = it.next();`

Shouldn't the `while(it.hasNext())` prevent that?

Comment: `final Set<Person> unqiuePeople = new TreeSet<Person>(persons)` will do what you want in one line.

Comment: With the appropriately defined comparator/equals() method

Comment: @BrianAgnew given that the OP is already using `Collections.sort` to order the items I assume this is already defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `it.next()` twice, which will advance the iterator two times.

You should store the value to avoid repeating the side-effect.

```
    Person person = it.next();
    if (tmp.getLastDiscovered() == person.getLastDiscovered()) {
        getHelper().delete(tmp);
    }
    tmp = person;
```

Alternatively, you could use the for-each loop to avoid needing to interact with the iterators (I assume all `Person` are not null):

```
Person tmp = null;
for (Person person : persons) {
    if (tmp != null && tmp.getLastDiscovered() == person.getLastDiscovered()) {
        getHelper().delete(tmp);
    }
    tmp = person;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `it.next()` twice (potentially) for each `it.hasNext()` call, hence your error.

If you want to remove duplicates, why not just populate a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (providing the appropriate Comparator) with your list ? The semantics of a `Set` are such that you'll have a distinct set of elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
        if(tmp.getLastDiscovered() == it.next().getLastDiscovered()) {
            getHelper().delete(tmp);
        }
```

After that 'while' you are coming to end of the list. Then when it hasn't got next value, you are calling the line below.

```
tmp = it.next();
```

That gives you an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JDK 1.5.0 or later (which you most likely are, since it was released in 2004), you can use a [foreach loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop#Java) to obviate the iterator altogether, greatly simplifying the code.

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = getHelper().findAllPersons();
Collections.sort(persons);
for (Person person : persons) {
    if(tmp.getLastDiscovered() == person.getLastDiscovered()) {
        getHelper().delete(tmp);
    }
}
```